# Why are environment variables in cmd and Console2 different?

Tags: environment-variables, console2

I installed [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) to replace the Windows default console.

I set the console2 shell as `cmd.exe`. Everything is okay.

But today, I added maven's path in PATH variables, and execute `mvn` command, it was not recognized.

So I tried the command in `cmd.exe`, and it's okay.

Console2 should be only a wrapper for cmd, why the environment variable is not affected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say console2 is only a shell for cmd.exe

It didn't change the environment of the system.

so they are always the same.

did you restart the console2? Try to restart console2 and it will be ok.

Answer (score 1):

May be It need to restart Windows?

Today, I found the PATH back.